# How to use the unsized type in Rust

Tags: rust

I read the documentation for Sized trait https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html.
And I found this piece of code:

```
struct Bar<T: ?Sized>(T);
struct BarUse(Bar<[i32]>);
```

Then I tried many different ways (like below) to create an object of `BarUse`, but but it's always unsuccessful.

```
struct Bar<T: ?Sized>(T);
struct BarUse(Bar<[i32]>);

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar([1, 2, 3]);
    let bar_use = BarUse(bar);
}
```

Can someone show me the code that can get an object of BarUse (reference and pointer is also good)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsized types always have to come behind some indirection. For example, `Box`:

```rust
struct Bar<T: ?Sized>(T);
struct BarUse(Box<Bar<[i32]>>);

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar([1, 2, 3]);
    let bar_use = BarUse(Box::new(bar));
}
```

But if we want to leave `BarUse` as-is, and box the `BarUse`, then unfortunately we can't do that.

Custom unsized types are only half supported; they're possible to *write*, but they're pretty much impossible to *instantiate* unless they are generic (barring unsafe code).

Comment: Thanks Chayim! But the code `struct BarUse(Bar<[i32]>);` is from the Rust official documentation, so I think it should be able to instantiate or it should have some other usage.

Comment: @Benjamin I think it only used to demonstrate the idea of `?Sized` bounds. Anyway, [you can construct it using unsafe code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b3e641d40a2b60fb33bbf8b755ad262), but not without it.

Comment: I see @Chayim Friedman Thanks so much Chayim!